# How to put file from android app to pc in LAN network

Tags: android, windows, android-activity, share

I have a little problem with my android app. I'm developing an android app that should read .txt file from PC, and path is "E:/Sharing/hello.txt". I already shared that folder on PC. How can I get that file and read it on my android app. Is there any solution, or someone have example how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can do in many ways here:

1. You need to write 2 app, one in android [as client], another on in desktop [as server]

   this way, you need to connect your android to server app, and let server app handle all about  find files and transfer to your android app
2. Easier way, you just need to use some Data's storage service, such as Google Drive, Dropbox, Microsoft OneDrive, etc.

   to let them auto sync all your file and put it in their site, then, you just need to (install their app in your android or) download your file directly from their site.
3. Easiest way, from your desktop, just send file to your android's register email. after that just download it from Google Gmail

> I suggested, 2 and 3 (even if it doesn't relate to programming) because it is easier than 1 alot, and many
> people also accepted to used it in real-life